# Unique dropdowns on Kendo Grid MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I need to create a grid in which **column#2** dropdownlist changes for each value **column#1** (which is a simple text) might have.

**Column#1** contains the name of a table and **column#2** has to be filled with those values.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Cascading Dropdowns](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/dropdownlist/cascadingdropdownlist). The whole purpose is to have these dependent dropdowns.